# SocialEngine 4 - Blank Sign Up & Sign In pages... :-/

Tags: php, socialengine

Wondering if someone can help...

I am running PHP 5.3.6, on Windows Server 2008 R2, with IIS 7.5 & Helicon APE (Apache module for .htaccess files)

I have a legitimate serial number from socialengine.net (although my support tickets have expired.)

I downloaded 4.1.8p1 from "My Account" and unzipped directly into the web root (no need to FTP as I'm working directly on the host server)

I went through the install with no probs, everything went as expected.

When I goto "Sign In" or "Sign Up" I get nothing but a blank page.  As far as I know all folders that require the 755 equivalent are set.  I can upload & activate plugins with no probs etc.

Development mode reveals nothing, and even with all error reporting on in php.ini I still don't get any error... FirePHP doesn't report anything either (except the norm debug info)

I currently have no 3rd party plugins installed, it is a brand new installation, yet the 2 pages just will not work :( :(

Anyone got any ideas on how I can find out what the problem is??

Domain is [http://dance-network.net](http://www.dance-network.net)

Many thanks in advance!

[Proof of purchase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL5ip.jpg)

Comment: have you looked at the view templates for those pages?

Comment: Yup - no dice :-/ Annoyingly, the Privacy, Terms & Conditions and Contact Us pages are all blank as well!! I just have no idea :(

Answer (score 0):

A blank page usually means a PHP script error. We suggest going through the code of the page that is not showing up and trying to print errors with:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

However some servers (such as the ones that run on Parallels Plesk) have error reporting disabled. We suggest enabling error reporting or going through line by line with print statements to see where the error might be occurring.